# Loading json on external classin android

Tags: android, json

I have been loading my jsonstring at the first fragment and transfered it using bundle to other fragments that use this json. However, developer console started to show errors talking about crashes related to the fact that my json that I was transfering as string is too long to process within the standard time. So I've decided to load it on each fragment that use json. To make it more accurate I've decided also to move the code to separate class and call it each time from there. 
Here is the problem. I can't seems to understand how to initialize this class and receive the value from it ?

```
class mrjson {

String jsonString;
public Context ctx;



    public String loadmyjson() {
        InputStream is = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.feeder);
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, 
"UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n=reader.read(buffer)) !=-1){
                writer.write(buffer,0,n);
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        jsonString = writer.toString();

return jsonString;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I've tried to google it, but all it gives is paid classes for android.

Comment: are you doing this on main thread?

Comment: @Arpit, yes trying to initialize it on my fragment

Comment: Years ago i think for bundle the max size you could  send was **1Mb** . I don't think is a good practice send big data via intent  , what i can suggest to you is write to a file and read from file when you need .

Comment: @Frank if it will be more than 1MB , then there will be transactionTooLarge exception thrown.
Also, I suggest you to do the reading in worker thread.

Comment: @Arpit, thank you've managed to overcome this issue by the use of runnable and handler